# flywaydb cannot connect with mysql db

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to migrate my database using flywaydb using the Java app. I am doing via code

```
flwayObj = new FlyWay()
flywayObj.setDataSource("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mydb", "user", "pass");
flywayObj.setLocations("location");
flywayObj.migrate()
```

But I get the following error

```
Unable to connect to the database. Configure the url, user and password!
```

I know they are correct since it the same url user and pass hibernate and jpa are using. Shouldn't be able to connect?

Comment: Try connecting to your DB via whatever external tool (MySQL Admin or whatever) you use, and take a look at the connection parameters used by that. You could be running into issues with the IP address resolving differently from where FlyWay is executed compared to your test computer, or you could just have the wrong username or password, or some other part of the connection string.

Comment: Value of url is copy pasted an username and password are both root. Bit difficult to type the wrong.. Is there a specific setting I missed?